# Is there any rest API or SDK from microsoft Azure which will give me list of all images on azure galary?

Tags: azure, rest, api

I need a rest api which will list out all the images available with azure market place with its Location,publisher and SKU.

Answer (score 2):

Here are available [Azure REST API for Virtual Machine Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineimages). You can find an image in 3 steps referring to [Navigate the images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage#navigate-the-images):

> 1. List the image publishers.
> 2. For a given publisher, list their offers.
> 3. For a given offer, list their SKUs.

Then, for a selected SKU, get a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineimages/list) of all virtual machine image versions for the specified location, publisher, offer, and SKU to deploy.

[List Offers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineimages/listoffers)
Gets a list of virtual machine image offers for the specified location and publisher.

[List Publishers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineimages/listpublishers)
Gets a list of virtual machine image publishers for the specified Azure location.

[List Skus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineimages/listskus)
Gets a list of virtual machine image SKUs for the specified location, publisher, and offer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Azure Stack Admin API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure-stack/)

Especially to get the list of images , you need **[`Gallery Items - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azurestack/galleryitems/list)**

> GET
>   https://adminmanagement.local.azurestack.external/subscriptions/0ff0bbbe-d68d-4314-8f68-80a808b5a6ec/providers/microsoft.gallery.admin/galleryItems?api-version=2015-04-01